# Why does ZeroMQ not receive a string when it becomes too large on a PUSH/PULL MT4 - Python setup?

Tags: zeromq, distributed-system, mql4, low-latency, metatrader4

I have an EA set in place that loops history trades and builds one large string with trade information. I then send this string every second from MT4 to the python backend using a plain `PUSH/PULL` pattern.

For whatever reason, the data isn't received on the pull side when the string transferred becomes too long. The backend `PULL`-socket slices each string and further processes it.

Any chance that the `PULL`-side is too slow to grab and **process** all the data which then causes an overflow (so that a delay arises due to the processing part)?

Talking about file sizes we are well below **5kb per second.**

This is the `PULL`-socket, which manipulates the data after receiving it:

```
while True:
    # check 24/7 for available data in the pull socket
    try:
        msg = zmq_socket.recv_string()
        data = msg.split("|")
        print(data)

        # if data is available and msg is account info, handle as follows
        if data[0] == "account_info":
[...]
    except zmq.error.Again:
        print("\nResource timeout.. please try again.")
        sleep(0.000001)
```

I am a bit curious now since the pull socket seems to not even be able to process a string containing 40 trades with their according information on a single MT4 client - Python connection. I actually planned to set it up to handle more than 5.000 MT4 clients - python backend connections at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q** : ***Any chance*** that the pull side is too slow to grab and process all the data which then causes **an overflow** (so that a delay arises **due to the processing part**)?

Zero chance.

Sending 640 B each second is **definitely** no showstopper <sub>( *5kb per second* - is nowhere near a performance ceiling... )</sub>

The posted problem formulation is otherwise undecidable.

**Step 1)** `POSACK/NACK` prove whether a **`PUSH`** side accepts the payload for sending error-free.

**Step 2)** prove the **`PULL`** side is not to be blamed - `[PUSH.send(640*chr(64+i)) for i in range( 10 )]` via a python-2-python `tcp://`-transport-class solo-channel crossing host-to-host hop, over at least your local physical network ( no VMCI/emulated vLAN, no other localhost colocation )

**Step 3)** if either steps above got `POSACK`-ed, your next chances are the ZeroMQ configuration space and/or the MT4-based `PUSH`-side incompatibility, most probably "hidden" inside a (not mentioned) third party ZeroMQ wrapper used / first-party issues with `string` handling / processing ( which you must have already read about, as it has been so many times observed and mentioned in the past posts about this trouble with well "hidden" MQL4 internal eco-system changes ).

Anyway, stay tuned. ZeroMQ is a sure bet and a truly horsepower for professional and [low-latency](/questions/tagged/low-latency) designs in [distributed-system](/questions/tagged/distributed-system)'s domain.